# Can't enter text in collapsable force directed graph d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

Hello dear Stackoverflow community, 
I've come far with my force-directed graph and am really enjoying the project. Yet I keep failing when it comes to entering text elements on the nodes. Please find two images attached, one with my current nodes and one with the labels I'd like to have.

[image]

[image]
Source: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130

Below you'll find the code snippet I'd like to include:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

I've added a //text comment in the area where I have tested the code above.

I've tried a group  element in svg.selectAll & .append("circle"). This however broke the visual. What am I missing?
Thank you for your support and happy weekend!

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/01fcb12790.js">//fontawesome for searchbar
</script> 


<script>

var width = 960,
  height = 960,
  root;

// d3 overview: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3/workshop/#121
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  .linkDistance(100) //How far apart the nodes are
  .charge(-50) //how far are the group nodes from each other
  .gravity(0.001) //how far away are the nodes from each other
  .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
  node = svg.selectAll(".node");

  d3.json("readme.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = json;
  update();
});

function update() {
var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);


// Restart the force layout.
force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

// Update the links…
link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

// Exit any old links.
link.exit().remove();

// Enter any new links.
link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

// Update the nodes…
node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; }).style("fill", color);

// Exit any old nodes.
node.exit().remove();

// Enter any new nodes.
node.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 10.5; })
    .style("fill", color)
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);

  }
//text


//creating the tick function from the force variable
//the "e" paramater can be used for positioning


function tick() {
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
return d._children ? "#E83E1D" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
var nodes = [], i = 0;

function recurse(node) {
  if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
  if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
  nodes.push(node);
}

recurse(root);
return nodes;
}

// Tag animation begin.

//Tag animation end


</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could create a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io) and put your code there (including the data you're using)?